# browser calling request twice one time is preflight

Tags: php, http, request, http-headers, preflight

Hello I'm trying to send mail via php with mandrill, but have problems with preflight request - sending email twice, but first time without values from request

here is php code:

```
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];    
try {
    if ($method == "OPTIONS") {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header(
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization"
        );
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        die();
    } else {
        $user_request->update_request_status();
        $mandrill_request_data = get_mandril_request_data($user_request);
        email($mandrill_request_data);
        die();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

I've tried this way, but without solving problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're setting `$method` correctly?

Comment: I already added so I think yes

Comment: If you check the browser's Network tab, do you see it sending the `OPTIONS` request before the `POST` request?

Comment: When I look to the browser waterfalls, POST request send after OPTION

Comment: It's only sending one POST request, but your `else` code is running twice? I can't see how that's happening. What do you see in the server access log?

Comment: Have you actually debugged and logged what $method is each time? I agree I don't see how this would happen. Seems far more likely the script is being called twice as a POST for some other reason

Comment: I return back new code from git history and it is working now :|